# git add submodule without repo name

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have 2 repositories at github: 1st is for a cURL library, 2nd is for a project I'm writing. I'm trying to add my library as submodule to my project:

```
cd /www/fifa14api/CI-FIFA14-API/
git submodule add git@github.com:ctepeo/CI-cURL.git
```

My project based on CodeIgniter, so file structure looks like

```
/application/
/system/
index.php
```

My library at repo have prepared for CodeIgniter structure:

```
/application/
     /libraries/
         curl.php
```

When I add submodule, I want to "merge" them (to put my curl.php at right directory in project), but it creates CI-cURL *(repo name)* folder at root, so I got

```
/application/
/system/
/CI-cURL/
    /application/
        curl.php
index.php
```

How can I (and is it possible?) to exclude repository's name when adding submodule?

Comment: Since 2014 quite a lot of things changed and nowadays I'd recommend to use package managers for libraries (like i needed cURL one) and keep it into two different repos for sources. And then just to add a package with cURL into the project (via composer for php in this specific question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git submodules are fully-fledged git repositories, so you can't check out just part of a git repo using submodules: it needs to have its own folder. You can, however, name that folder whatever you like: `git submodule add git@hostname:location.git path/to/module` clones the submodule to `path/to/module` in your git repo.

Comment: So there's no way to implement library from one github repo to another project? I don't think so.

Comment: No, that's not what I said: you can't just get one file from a github repo. You could mount the submodule's git repository in `application/libraries/CI-cURL/` just fine. You could also mount it in `application/libraries/` but then you won't be able to add other libraries: dropping them in `application/libraries` would add them to the CI-cURL repo.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for explanation, I do not understand correctly first. I'll restructure my lib and put it directly to my libraries' folder with CI-cURL folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), "[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d8b0ec44b13f7ee4dd6c8c726b5c105f66a51329/Documentation/git-add.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> and [`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d8b0ec44b13f7ee4dd6c8c726b5c105f66a51329/Documentation/git-stash.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> learned to support the "`:(attr:...)`" magic pathspec.

That means your scenario (submodules without a repo name) is supported:

```
git add . ':(exclude,attr:submodule)'
```

See [commit 1164c72](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1164c7232e2773917c0fcf9a98b3e7a417a7644f) (03 Nov 2023) by [Joanna Wang (`joannajw`)](https://github.com/joannajw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d8b0ec4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8b0ec44b13f7ee4dd6c8c726b5c105f66a51329), 09 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`attr`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1164c7232e2773917c0fcf9a98b3e7a417a7644f): enable attr pathspec magic for git-add and git-stash
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Joanna Wang</sup>

> Allow users to limit or exclude files based on file attributes during [`git-add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1164c7232e2773917c0fcf9a98b3e7a417a7644f/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> and git-stash.
>
> For example, the chromium project would like to use
>
> ```
> $ git add . ':(exclude,attr:submodule)'
> ```
>
> as **submodules are managed by an external tool**, forbidding end users to record changes with `git add`.
> Allowing "`git add`" to often records changes that users do not want in their commits.
>
> This commit does not change any attr magic implementation.
> It is only adding attr as an allowed pathspec in `git-add` and `git-stash`, which was previously blocked by `GUARD_PATHSPEC` and a pathspec mask in `parse_pathspec()`).
>
> However, we fix a bug in `prefix_magic()` where attr values were unintentionally removed.
> This was triggerable when `parse_pathspec()` is called with `PATHSPEC_PREFIX_ORIGIN` as a flag, which was the case for `git-stash` (Bug originally [filed here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAMmZTi-0QKtj7Q=sbC5qhipGsQxJFOY-Qkk1jfkRYwfF5FcUVg@mail.gmail.com/))
>
> Furthermore, while other commands hit this code path it did not result in unexpected behavior because this bug only impacts the `pathspec->items->original` field which is NOT used to filter paths.
> However, [`git-stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1164c7232e2773917c0fcf9a98b3e7a417a7644f/Documentation/git-stash.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> does use `pathspec->items->original` when building args used to call other git commands.
> (See `add_pathspecs()` usage and implementation in `stash.c`)
>
> It is possible that when the attr pathspec feature was first added in [b0db704](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0db70465246bb8309d3d12c9bc34ac3f0c1e203) ("`pathspec`: allow querying for attributes", 2017-03-13, Git v2.13.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6c64c648ade843b44d517b2de41b8b882f112c0) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d77b0405ce6b471cb5ce3a904368fc25e55643d)), `"PATHSPEC_ATTR"` was just unintentionally left out of a few `GUARD_PATHSPEC()` invocations.
>
> Later, to get a more user-friendly error message when attr was used with `git-add`, `PATHSPEC_ATTR` was added as a mask to git-add's invocation of `parse_pathspec()` [84d938b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84d938b732242e81ec68647994070eb7c34d061f) ("`add`: do not accept pathspec magic 'attr'", 2018-09-18, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faadedb19538a9968dd2d607bcab00be1916bd31) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe8321ec057f9231c26c29b364721568e58040f7)).
> However, this user-friendly error message was never added for git-stash.